# Older Snapshot folder content is not deleting automatically (Snapshot Replication)

Tags: t-sql, database-replication

I am using SQL 2017, SSMS v19.0.2

I successfully set up snapshot replication, but had to disable it when I saw disk space being consumed.

The distribution cleanup job is running successfully but reports no deletions:

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
> system administrator. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 2528)  Deleted 0
> row(s) per millisecond from MSrepl_commands [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message
> 22121)  Deleted 0 row(s) per millisecond from MSrepl_transactions
> [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 22121)  Removed 0 replicated transactions
> consisting of 0 statements in 10 milliseconds (0 rows/millisec).
> [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 21010).  The step succeeded.

When I purposefully exec the stored procedure, I also get a success message but the files and folders remain:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_MSdistribution_cleanup @min_distretention = 0, @max_distretention = 6
```

If I understand things correctly, if I manually kick off the distribution cleanup job, I should get files deleted.

I have had errors from the snapshot agent, but I am working through those as separate issues. The two (unrelated in my mind errors I am working through):

1. Database '...' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore. (I can schedule things better.)
2. Reference to database and/or server name in '...' is not supported in this version of SQL Server." (I will dig into that view, I am sure.)

I understand from [another SE post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81030/replication-snapshot-folder-not-cleaning-up), that:

> The snapshot agent will only try once to remove the previous snapshot
> files so if those files were locked at that moment (by the merge agent
> e.g.), it is possible that snapshot files will be left over.

I don't think locking is the issue but these files are on a network share, so I am thinking a permission issue. I am perplexed that the enabled snapshot replication process that creates its own jobs can write the files to the location, but cannot delete them without at least reporting a failure to do so.

I am looking for advice on troubleshooting such as issue without the benefit of an error message.

1. Does the absence of an error message itself suggest a root cause?
2. Might I find an error message somewhere else, such as Event Viewer?
3. I have verified that xp_cmdshell is enabled on the server.
4. I believe I should be able to validate a fix is successful by manual execution of dbo.sp_MSdistribution_cleanup with parameters guaranteed to delete some of the files from disk. Can executing this remove files without the agent running? Please let me know if there is a better/different certificate of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a new snapshot folder with wide open security and re-created the replication using that folder. Then, it cleaned up itself as expected. So, there was some security issue with the folder it appears, that neither I nor the hosting company could determine.